# JsonIgnore attribute is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

My model is

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Login { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

and controller method is

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
        }
```

I am using adding newtonsoft to a project in Program.cs like that:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

And when i try to post user in postman, i getting validation error neither i am including email field or not:

```
"errors": {
        "Email": [
            "The Email field is required."
        ]
    },
```

I tried different ways of including newtonsoft in Program.cs, also i tried to make my model with [DataContract] excluding email field. If i remove builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson() then with email field validation is passing, but without it still failing. using System.Text.Json.Serialization not working too. What can i do?

Comment: The syntax looks correct. Have you tried making email a nullable string; `public string? Email { get; set; }`

Comment: Wow, don't even thought about it. Now it is working, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed validation problem after making string nullable,
 `public string? Email { get; set; }`